# Used AppCenter to download Mozilla Firefox, but Files shows no .tar or download

Tags: pantheon-files, appcenter, firefox

I've been using Epiphany for a couple of days, but have encountered a problem with Google Voice that I think Firefox would "solve." Instead of downloading on my own, I dutifully used the AppCenter, so that elementary would "know" that I have installed the app.
Now Mozilla Firefox is on my list of installed applications but I cannot open it via AppCenter, and cannot locate it via Files. (Searched for "Mozilla" "Firefox" and ".tar")

I feel like I've "played by the rules," and that didn't work. I'd love suggestions for elementary actions that could move me forward (and perhaps teach me something about elementary). Should I uninstall, and then reinstall Firefox through AppCenter, and why would that work when it didn't initially?

---

I'm embarrassed to write that I solved my problem, and didn't document it. My guess, though, is that I went back to the Applications drop down, and saw Firefox "all of a sudden."

Thank you - I appreciate both answers I received, and (as I explained) didn't want to immediately go to Terminal and start using the power of the command line, so as to give elementaryOS a chance to stay well-integrated.

Comment: Using the AppCenter to uninstall was not successful, because "Operation was cancelled." And I can sort of understand that, since I can't see any files that it would uninstall...

Comment: This issue may be related: https://github.com/elementary/appcenter/issues/1378.  It helps if you state which version of elementaryOS you are using. Files only searches below the current folder (and in bookmarks), not the whole filesystem (unless you navigate to /)

Comment: Thank you for the tip about Files, and I'll remember to send it to root if I'm in a parallel situation. I see from System Settings > About that I'm using elementary OS 5.1.7 Hera

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively you can also simply install it via Flatpak just by clicking on the "Install" button in the Flathub page for Firefox: https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.mozilla.firefox

This flatpak package is directly maintained by Mozilla.

Answer (score 1):

You can install via command line with `sudo apt install firefox`

Comment: Thank you, and I'm aware of the power of the command line. I was trying to do things in a way that elementary os would recognize, so that I didn't confuse it.